# How do I Implement a application/vnd.api+json media type in Spring-Rest?

Tags: json, spring, json-api, spring-rest

I've seen other cases where people try and modify the HAL formatted code to fit the JSON API media type. I don't think this is the right approach. I want to accept a new header type. What are the right classes in Spring to do this with? Will I have to modify the underlying Spring source to achieve this? Any help is a ppreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring relies on the Jackson libraries for REST support, maybe try asking on their forums what their plans for JSON-API are?

http://jackson-users.ning.com/